# How to convert a list of Numpy arrays to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, type-conversion, numpy-ndarray

I have a list of Numpy arrays that looks like this:

```
[400.31865662]
[401.18514808]
[404.84015554]
[405.14682194]
[405.67735105]
[273.90969447]
[274.0894528]
```

When I try to convert it to a Pandas Dataframe with the following code

```
y = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(y)
```

I get the following output when printing it. Why do I get all those zeros?

```
            0
0  400.318657
            0
0  401.185148
            0
0  404.840156
            0
0  405.146822
            0
0  405.677351
            0
0  273.909694
            0
0  274.089453
```

I would like to get a single column dataframe which looks like that:

```
400.31865662
401.18514808
404.84015554
405.14682194
405.67735105
273.90969447
274.0894528
```

Comment: You must be doing something else, because I get exactly what you'd expect.  What exactly does `data` look like before you create the `DataFrame`? It looks like each item is its own `DataFrame`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error, can you post the `print(data)`?. A dataframe needs to have an index (row indicator) and a column name (column indicator). If you do not provide them, pandas will create them automatically: you should see 0,1,2.. in rows and 0 in columns when calling `print(df)`. If you want to see only the data, use `y.values`

Comment: the issue is with your array:  `array = np.array(np.random.randn(5))` then `pd.DataFrame(array)`. Works as one would expect.

Comment: You are right Andrew (data) is indeed a list of arrays I did not realize it. So how can I aggregate them into a single array so that I can convert it to a Pandas dataframe?

Comment: As (data) is actually a list of array I tried the following code: 

`newdf = pd.DataFrame(data)
newdf.to_csv('test.csv',mode='w', sep=',',header=False,index=False)`

The result I get is only the last array of the list which is `274.08945279667057`. How can I concatenate the list of arrays into the same file?

Answer (score 21):

You could [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html#numpy-ndarray-flatten) the numpy array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [[400.31865662],
        [401.18514808],
        [404.84015554],
        [405.14682194],
        [405.67735105],
        [273.90969447],
        [274.0894528]]

arr = np.array(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr.flatten())

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
            0
0  400.318657
1  401.185148
2  404.840156
3  405.146822
4  405.677351
5  273.909694
6  274.089453
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the issue, because `pd.DataFrame(data)` works even if you don't flatten the data. The problem is something else, and this may or may not have solved OP's problem in the end.

Comment: All great answers above, one other thing one can do is to add a column name if that helps `df = pd.DataFrame(data=arr.flatten(), columns=['Values'])`

Answer (score 16):

Since I assume the many visitors of this post aren't here for OP's specific and un-reproducible issue, **here's a general answer**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array)
```

The strength of `pandas` is to be nice for the eye (like Excel), so it's important to use column names.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

array = np.random.rand(5, 5)
```

```
array([[0.723, 0.177, 0.659, 0.573, 0.476],
       [0.77 , 0.311, 0.533, 0.415, 0.552],
       [0.349, 0.768, 0.859, 0.273, 0.425],
       [0.367, 0.601, 0.875, 0.109, 0.398],
       [0.452, 0.836, 0.31 , 0.727, 0.303]])
```

```
columns = [f'col_{num}' for num in range(5)]
index = [f'index_{num}' for num in range(5)]
```

**Here's where the magic happens:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(array, columns=columns, index=index)
```

```
            col_0     col_1     col_2     col_3     col_4
index_0  0.722791  0.177427  0.659204  0.572826  0.476485
index_1  0.770118  0.311444  0.532899  0.415371  0.551828
index_2  0.348923  0.768362  0.858841  0.273221  0.424684
index_3  0.366940  0.600784  0.875214  0.108818  0.397671
index_4  0.451682  0.836315  0.310480  0.727409  0.302597
```

Answer (score 5):

There is another way, which isn't mentioned in the other answers. If you have a NumPy array which is essentially a row vector (or column vector) i.e. shape like `(n, )` , then you could do the following :

```
# sample array
x = np.zeros((20))
# empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
# add the array to df as a column
df['column_name'] = x
```

This way you can add multiple arrays as separate columns.

Answer (score 4):

I just figured out my mistake. (data) was a list of arrays:

```
[array([400.0290173]), array([400.02253235]), array([404.00252113]), array([403.99466754]), array([403.98681395]), array([271.97896036]), array([271.97110677])]
```

So I used `np.vstack(data)` to concatenate it

```
conc = np.vstack(data)

[[400.0290173 ]
 [400.02253235]
 [404.00252113]
 [403.99466754]
 [403.98681395]
 [271.97896036]
 [271.97110677]]
```

Then I convert the concatened array into a Pandas Dataframe by using the

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(conc)


    0
0  400.029017
1  400.022532
2  404.002521
3  403.994668
4  403.986814
5  271.978960
6  271.971107
```

Et voilà!